# How does the population fitness change after a change in mutation rate?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, population-dynamics, population-biology, population-genetics

The mean population fitness as given by mutation load theory depends only on the genome-wide mutation rate ($U$). My question is: **How many generations is needed to reach a new mutation load equilibrium after a change in $U$?**

---

Following is an article were they perform the kind of calculations I am interested in:

Let $U$ be the genome-wide mutation rate, $\delta U$ a change (between two time steps) in the genome-wide mutation rate and $s$ the mutational effect (effect on fitness) of a given mutation. In [Agrawal and Whitlock (2012)](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-ecolsys-110411-160257), page 13 (or 127 in the journal), $3^{rd}$ paragraph, the authors say:

> [After a change in $U$,] it can take a long time to approach mutation-selection balance. For example, if the mutation rate is increased by $\delta U = 1$ deleterious mutation per genome per generation, then it would take ∼120 generations for fitness to decline 80% of its expected amount if s = 0.01. However, by obtaining a time series of data, one could infer the equilibrium load after tens or hundreds of generations even if equilibrium is not reached

**How were these ~120 generations estimated/calculated?**